# How similar are Soyuz and Progress?

Tags: iss, soyuz-spacecraft, russia, progress

Superficially the Soyuz and Progress spacecraft look very similar:

[image: Soyuz TMA-7]
(Soyuz TMA-7)

[image: Progress M-52]
(Progress M-52)

So it would be easy to imagine that they share a common service module and/or orbital module. But does anyone know if this is the case, or how many common systems they do in fact share?

Comment: Hmm, just curious. What are the two light coloured things hanging on some kind of chain in the lower right corner of Progress photo?

Comment: @sharptooth They're on both photographs. They're the two aft [Kurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurs_%28docking_system%29) antennae (radio telemetry) that deploy together with the solar panels and the communications antenna (better seen on the top photo, bottom right). There's two more Kurs antennae at the front of the Soyuz / Progress craft. Refer e.g. to [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_%28spacecraft%29#Spacecraft_systems).

Comment: Progress is an unmanned Soyuz-derived spacecraft that its sole purpose is to deliver supplies to a location usually the Interational Space Station.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are essentially the same. The Progress resupply spacecraft is a direct derivative of the Soyuz, where the reentry module was replaced by a fuel tank. Hence the similar shape.

Both are launched with the same Soyuz rockets.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the obvious: the life-support systems were stripped out, saving weight and space, along with the solid-fuel retro-rockets that Soyuz uses to soften landings, etc. But yah, Rikki's answer is correct!

Comment: This [picture](https://blogs.nasa.gov/spacestation/wp-content/uploads/sites/240/2016/04/ISS_04-02-16.jpg) lead me to this question/answer. Indeed @Kirkaiya , it could be an important distinction in an emergency, faced with a small parking-lot full of spacecraft.

Comment: @Kirkaiya: Don't forget the heatshield (also removed).

Comment: Yep, in a pinch Progress could bring an astronaut or two (wearing spacesuits and with some life-support modules) from Earth to ISS, but not down. It has no reentry capacity and is designed to burn up in the upper atmosphere, whole.

Comment: @Vikki, the heat shield is part of the reentry module.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi: Of the Soyuz, yes.  Not of the Progress.

Answer (score 4):

The two photographs you have posted show that the Soyuz middle section is longer than the corresponding re-entry module of Soyuz.

You can also see the differences between the Soyuz and Progress here [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_(spacecraft)). They are significantly different in that for Progress the re-entry capsule has been replaced and the ISS crew has no access other than to the orbital module.
The following text comes from the same wiki page:

> The reentry module of the Soyuz was replaced with an unpressurized propellant and refueling compartment with ducting along the outside of the spacecraft. This meant that if a leak occurred, the poisonous gas would not enter the station's atmosphere. The fuel is carried in two tanks.

The wiki page also shows these diagrams:
[image]

[image]

Thus you can see that the Progress is quite different, not at all "essentially the same", as replacing the re-entry module with a module for carrying propellants completely changes the concept of operations of the vehicle.

Comment: The link to wikipedia has a typo